# Как расположить fullscreen виджет по центру экрана?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qlayout

Делаем скриншот экрана, и в `QLabel` выводим его на экран без рамок и кнопок и получаем немного съехавшее окно вправо вниз, как на скриншоте (белая рамка слева и сверху).

1. Дело в QGridLayout?
2. Как исправить?

[image: screenshot]

Как расположить `fullscreen` виджет по центру экрана?

**main.py**:

```
class MainWindow(QWidget):
def __init__(self):
    super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
    self.screenshot = QApplication.primaryScreen().grabWindow(0)
    self.settings()
    self.create_widgets()
    self.set_layout()

def settings(self):
    self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
    self.setWindowState(QtCore.Qt.WindowFullScreen)

def create_widgets(self):
    self.image_preview = QLabel()
    self.image_preview.setPixmap(self.screenshot)

def set_layout(self):
    self.layout = QGridLayout(self)
    self.layout.addWidget(self.image_preview, 0, 0, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.setLayout(self.layout)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> void QLayout::setContentsMargins(int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
>
> Устанавливает левое, верхнее, правое и нижнее поля для использования вокруг макета. По умолчанию QLayout использует значения, предоставленные стилем. На большинстве платформ поле составляет 11 пикселей во всех направлениях.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import  *
from PyQt5.QtGui import  *


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        
        self.screenshot = QApplication.primaryScreen().grabWindow(0)
        self.settings()
        self.create_widgets()
        self.set_layout()

    def settings(self):
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setWindowState(Qt.WindowFullScreen)

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.image_preview = QLabel()
        self.image_preview.setPixmap(self.screenshot)

    def set_layout(self):
        self.layout = QGridLayout(self)
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)                                    # <---
        self.layout.addWidget(self.image_preview, 0, 0, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    a_window = MainWindow()
    a_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]